# In Tkinter, how to manage specific "functions" for checkboxes created with list()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox, range

I have these checkboxes and therefore i want to manage them as easily as possible (previously i had created them with place(x=..., y=...):

[image]

**PROBLEM:** For each checkbox i need a **different function**. By function i mean, for example, this:

```
 Checkbox1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="aaa", variable=self.My_Checkbutton1, 
             onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1, bg="white", foreground='black', 
             activebackground="white", highlightthickness=0,                                
             command = lambda: clicked(self.My_Checkbutton1.get(), funcyion_My_Checkbutton1))
```

so I need to manage a checkbox individually, except for its position which will automatically have to be positioned vertically

**P.S:** I need the above code of Checkbox1 to remain the same (with tk.Checkbutton command=lamba..., etc.), otherwise my whole project will break

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
cbframe = tk.Frame(root)
cbframe.pack(side="left", fill="y")

all_names = ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")
all_checkbuttons = {}

for name in all_names:
    myvar = tk.IntVar(root)

    combobox = tk.Checkbutton(cbframe, text=name, variable=myvar)
    combobox.pack(side="top", fill="x", anchor="w")
    
    #Checkbox 1 with its specific function
    Checkbox1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, 
    variable=self.My_Checkbutton1, 
    onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1, 
    bg="white", foreground='black', 
    activebackground="white", highlightthickness=0, 
    command = lambda: clicked(self.My_Checkbutton1.get(), function_My_Checkbutton1))

    #Checkbox 2 with its specific function
    Checkbox2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, 
    variable=self.My_Checkbutton2, 
    onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1, 
    bg="white", foreground='black', 
    activebackground="white", highlightthickness=0, 
    command = lambda: clicked(self.My_Checkbutton2.get(), function_My_Checkbutton2))

    #Checkbox 3 with its specific function
    ...

    if not i%2:
        sep = ttk.Separator(cbframe)
        sep.pack(side="top", fill="x")

tk.mainloop()
```

Thank you

Comment: @JRiggles No, that doesn't answer my question. Reading the title and the first rows of the question, mine and his question seemed similar, but continuing to read the content is different from what I asked

Comment: It sounds like you need a dictionary that maps the name of the checkbox to the index of the checkbox. Then you access the checkbox index through the dictionary. Are you wanting something that on demand adds a new checkbox or do you know all of the check box names in advance?

Comment: @stan61285
 Yes, maybe I really need that. The solutions of the other 2 users, although kind, did not satisfy me. Can you show me your solution? I will be happy to accept it in case of help. Yes, I know all the checkboxes in advance, but I note that I may change their position in the future. I am waiting for your kind solution. Bryan Oakley's answer comes close, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't run. For example, you use `self` but never define a class. You also never define the `clicked` function.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "different function" since the code uses the same function with different parameters. Do you literally need different functions, or the same function with different parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this would be different, instead of coding the function for each command assaigned specifically to every check-box, I would iterate over a list with the name of each check box with this bit of code:

```
cb_function = [key for key, var in cb_name.items() if var.get()]
cb_function = [item.lower() for item in cb_function]
```

and then have a function that calls each command outside of the code for the GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

cb_frame =tk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Check-boxes")
cb_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")

options=["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]

vars = {}
for cb_name in options:
    var = StringVar(value="")
    vars[cb_name] = var
    heck_button= Checkbutton(
    cb_frame,
    text=cb_name,
    variable=var,
    onvalue=cb_name,
    offvalue="",
    height=1, 
    bg="white", 
    foreground='black',
    activebackground="white",
    highlightthickness=0,
    )

for widget in cb_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't work, or rather it only works halfway. The specific naming of the buttons works correctly, but I see that there is no possibility to insert specific functions for each checkbox.

In my question, I clearly specified this part "Also for each checkbox, I would like to use this:"I need each checkbox to have those specific functions (command with lambda, variable, etc). Can you review your question please? I will be happy to accept your solution or that of the first one who helps me

Comment: you mean you want each checkbox to have a different function attached to it? I didn't include the function because I thought it would be the same for all checkboxes.

Comment: Exact. For each checkbox I need a different function. By "function" I mean, for example, that whole piece of code that is under my "Also for each checkbox, I would like to use this:" which will obviously change for each checkbox. P.S: If you change, for example, variable and command = lambda: clicked(self.My_Checkbutton1.get(), funcyion_My_Checkbutton1)), then my whole project breaks.

Comment: I improved my code and I have proposed a way you can code the command for each button in. At a point it becomes kinda complicated having to call a different command for each button. I would simply have a function **outside of the GUI code** that calls on each button's function. Btw, it would be a better idea if you had broken down your problem into multiple questions and not have everything in one question.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Maybe you complicated it a little too much. Thank you, you're kind, but I can't understand. Where should i write your two cb_functions exactly? And where is my code with command and variable?

Comment: As I said you are mentioning too many problems that need troubleshooting, so I can't really answer everything in one go, try implementing everything mentioned above, improve your question and try providing an example that doesn't work. You are only demanding your code to be made working and you aren't providing any attempts from yourself. Can't just randomly stitch code together. Post an updated question with the things you have tried and didn't work. Πατρίδα, ε πατρίδα.

Answer (score 0):

Store the names in a list. Iterate over these names, creating the widgets and adding them to a dictionary.

```
names = ("this", "that", "another one")
checkbuttons = {}
for name in names:
    …
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(…)
    checkbuttons[name] = cb
    …
```

You can then use something like `checkbuttons[“that”]` to refer to a specific checkbutton

If you need to call a function using the name or variable, you can use `lambda` or `functools.partial`. If you use `lambda` you must define default parameters that bind the correct value to the function.

For example, this is **wrong**:

```
myvar = tk.IntVar(root)
cb = tk.Checkbutton(..., command=lambda: some_function(myvar.get()))
```

The reason that is wrong is because `myvar` will be the value of `myvar` at the time that the function is called, not the value of `myvar` at the time you create the function.

The proper way to do it is to bind `myvar` to a default argument so that the default is set to the current value in the loop. In the following example, we set the `var` parameter to the value of `var` at the time that the button is created, rather than at the time it is executed.

```
myvar = tk.IntVar(root)
cb = tk.Checkbutton(..., command=lambda var=myvar: some_function(var.get()))
```